# MSSQL consulta anidada con multiples registros JSON

Tags: json, stored-procedure, mssql

tengo un problema que no logro resolver

estoy elaborando un procedimiento almacenado en MSSQL
que me de como resultado dos colecciones de datos en formato json que resultante de consultar datos de otra tabla.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FSP_TOPUSE]
    @server VARCHAR(20)
AS
...    
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @query nvarchar(4000);
    
    SET @query = N'
            SELECT JSON_ARRAY(SELECT Name FROM ['+ @server + N'].dbo.personaje) as users, JSON_ARRAY(SELECT At_mame FROM ['+ @server + N'].dbo.inventario) as items;';
    
    Exec sp_executeSql @query;
```

no se si pueda hacer esto en MSSQL pero en Mysql tengo algo muy similar usando JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT()) claro que lo tengo que preparar un poco mas pero me da el resultado requerido.
ayúdenme porfavor.